# Type Using Both Required and Partial

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm struggling to understand Advanced Types in Typescript.

I want a type that has both required properties and not required properties, but I would like to have the list of properties easily readable.

I have a list of required properties as a type, and a list of optional properties as another type.

```
type BaseProperties = 
    | 'price'
    | 'cost'
    | 'location';

type Features =
    | 'radio'
    | 'wings'
    | 'tires'
    | 'rockets'
    | 'slushie_machine';
```

I want my eventual type to be:

```
type WithFeatures = {
    price: string;
    cost: string;
    location: string;
    radio?: string | number;
    wings?: string | number;
    tires?: string | number;
    rockets?: string | number;
    slushie_machine?: string | number;
};
```

And then I would like an array of:

```
public ThingsWithFeatures: WithFeatures[] = [];
```

I tried:

```
type WithFeatures = Required<BaseProperties> & Partial<Features>;
```

...which did not work.

What do I need to do to use required and partial to get the `WithProperties` type as described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

It's not `BaseProperties` and `Features` that are required themselves (they are just string literal types and `Required<"foo">` is just `"foo"`), but the properties in an object bearing their names.

**Solution**

Transform your property names into object types that use them. The first type will be an object in which the keys are `BaseProperties` and the values are of type `string`. It can be constructed by saying:

```
Record<BaseProperties, string>
```

All properties are required by default, so we don't need the `Required` helper. We need `Partial` for the second type though.

```
Partial<Record<Features, string>>
```

The final shape is an intersection (`&`) of these two.

```
type WithFeatures = Record<BaseProperties, string> & Partial<Record<Features, string>>;
```

Comment: `Record` was what I needed. Thank you!